# How to access an array of JSON objects using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm learning how to access an array of JSON objects using AJAX but can't seem to access my data. I keep getting undefined when trying to access a certain value of object in the array. I know I have the data there as when I called console.log I got the result in the picture below...

I'm trying to get the first object in the array and get it's name value using this code...

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "web_services/cow/api.php",
    data: "{ rating: 4.7}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache : false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]['name']);
    },
    error: function(){
       alert("There was an error loggin in");
    }
});
});
```

But I only get undefined unfortunately. Would the way I'm implementing this be okay or is there a better way?

[image: Result of console.log]

Thank you very much for any help and taking the time to read my question.

Comment: try `data.data[0]['name']`

Comment: You have objects, not JSON. JSON is a data format (think of a text file) that can be converted into objects and arrays. If `data` is the object you've got in the image, then you can access it at `data.data[0].name`. You've got a bunch of nested objects and arrays.

Comment: Thanks guys that worked for me. Couldn't think why it wasn't working. Is the way I'm doing it incorrect? Want to make sure I know the right way to have this.

Comment: @SmiffyKmc It wasn't working before because you were accessing it incorrectly. Not much more to say on that.

Comment: @MikeC Cool! I guess it's the data's data array I'm accessing! Thanks very much everyone!